document.querySelector() returns null for an existing element
I have issues selecting certain elements on a specific web page, querySelector returns null unless I first go through one of the parent element.
I tried chaining them together but still I eventually hit a dead end, .children .childNodes and .childElementCount don't seem to see the children elements.
see console output or screenshot below :
console output + DOM
document
.querySelector('[name="tabs"]');
null

document
.querySelector('div[role="main"] > section.active')
.querySelector('[name="tabs"]');
<slot name="tabs">

document
.querySelector('div[role="main"] > section.active')
.querySelector('[name="tabs"]')
.querySelector('flexipage-tab2');
null

document
.querySelector('div[role="main"] > section.active')
.querySelector('[name="tabs"]')
.children;
Object {  }

document
.querySelector('div[role="main"] > section.active')
.querySelector('[name="tabs"]')
.childNodes;
Object {  }

document
.querySelector('div[role="main"] > section.active')
.querySelector('[name="tabs"]')
.childElementCount;
0 

<div class="split-right " data-aura-rendered-by="476:0;p" role="main">
    <section role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" class="tabContent active oneConsoleTab" data-aura-rendered-by="723:0" data-aura-class="oneConsoleTab" id="721:0">
        <!--render facet: 635:0--><!--render facet: 637:0-->
        <div tabindex="-1" class="oneWorkspace active hasFixedFooter navexWorkspace" data-aura-rendered-by="641:0" data-aura-class="navexWorkspace" id="633:0">
            <style data-aura-rendered-by="642:0"></style>
            <span role="presentation" tabindex="0" class="focus-mark accessibility-span" data-aura-rendered-by="644:0"></span>
            <div class="wsTabset oneConsoleTabset wsTabBarHidden navexConsoleTabset" data-aura-rendered-by="649:0" data-aura-class="navexConsoleTabset">
                <section role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" class="tabContent active oneConsoleTab" data-aura-rendered-by="863:0" data-aura-class="oneConsoleTab" id="861:0">
                    <!--render facet: 823:0--><!--render facet: 828:0--><!--render facet: 831:0--><!--render facet: 839:0-->
                    <div class="oneWorkspaceTabWrapper" data-aura-rendered-by="841:0" data-aura-class="oneWorkspaceTabWrapper">
                        <!--render facet: 842:0-->
                        <!--render facet: 789:0--><!--render facet: 794:0--><!--render facet: 797:0--><!--render facet: 805:0-->
                        <div class="windowViewMode-maximized active lafPageHost" data-aura-rendered-by="807:0" data-aura-class="lafPageHost">
                            <style data-aura-rendered-by="816:0" class="forceBrandBand" data-aura-class="forceBrandBand"></style>
                            <div id="brandBand_2" class="slds-brand-band slds-brand-band_cover slds-brand-band_medium slds-template_default forceBrandBand" data-aura-rendered-by="818:0" data-aura-class="forceBrandBand">
                                <!--render facet: 819:0-->
                                <div class="slds-template__container" data-aura-rendered-by="813:0">
                                    <!--render facet: 911:0-->
                                    <div data-aura-rendered-by="913:0" class="oneRecordHomeFlexipage2Wrapper" data-aura-class="oneRecordHomeFlexipage2Wrapper">
                                        <!--render facet: 914:0-->
                                        <div class="recordHomeFlexipage2" data-aura-rendered-by="915:0">
                                            <one-record-home-flexipage2 data-data-rendering-service-uid="287" data-aura-rendered-by="917:0">
                                                <forcegenerated-adg-rollup_component___force-generated__flexipage_-record-page class="adg-rollup-wrapped" style="display: block;">
                                                    <forcegenerated-flexipage class="forcegenerated-flexipage-module" style="display: block;" data-page-type="RecordPage">
                                                        <record_flexipage-desktop-record-page-decorator style="display: block;" lwc-rjusaruus2-host="">
                                                            <div lwc-rjusaruus2="" class="record-page-decorator">
                                                                <!---->
                                                                <records-record-layout-event-broker lwc-rjusaruus2="">
                                                                    <slot>
                                                                        <slot lwc-rjusaruus2="">
                                                                            <flexipage-record-home-template-desktop2 class="forcegenerated-flexipage-template" lwc-7gup6q4i4vf-host="">
                                                                                <div lwc-7gup6q4i4vf="" class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                                                                                    <div lwc-7gup6q4i4vf="" class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 row row-main">
                                                                                        <div lwc-7gup6q4i4vf="" class="column slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_8-of-12 slds-large-size_8-of-12 region-main">
                                                                                            <slot lwc-7gup6q4i4vf="" name="main">
                                                                                                <flexipage-component2 data-component-id="flexipage_tabset" data-target-selection-name="flexipage_tabset" slot="main" lwc-7uq5q81tcsp-host="">
                                                                                                    <slot lwc-7uq5q81tcsp="">
                                                                                                        <flexipage-tabset2>
                                                                                                            <div class="slds-tabs_card">
                                                                                                                <h2 class="slds-assistive-text">Onglets</h2>
                                                                                                                <lightning-tabset class="flexipage-tabset" lwc-53k3k3g5nb9-host="">
                                                                                                                    <div lwc-53k3k3g5nb9="" class="slds-tabs_default">
                                                                                                                        <!---->
                                                                                                                        <!---->
                                                                                                                        <slot lwc-53k3k3g5nb9="">
                                                                                                                            <slot name="tabs">
                                                                                                                                <flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-3" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-show" lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="customTab__item"></flexipage-tab2>
                                                                                                                                <flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-4" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="customTab2__item"></flexipage-tab2>
                                                                                                                                <flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-5" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="customTab3__item"></flexipage-tab2>
                                                                                                                                <flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-6" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="flexipage_tab1__item"></flexipage-tab2>
                                                                                                                                <flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-7" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="flexipage_tab4__item"></flexipage-tab2>
                                                                                                                                <flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-8" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="flexipage_tab3__item"></flexipage-tab2>
                                                                                                                                <flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-9" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="flexipage_tab2__item"></flexipage-tab2>
                                                                                                                            </slot>
                                                                                                                        </slot>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                                </lightning-tabset>
                                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                                        </flexipage-tabset2>
                                                                                                    </slot>
                                                                                                </flexipage-component2>
                                                                                            </slot>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </flexipage-record-home-template-desktop2>
                                                                        </slot>
                                                                    </slot>
                                                                </records-record-layout-event-broker>
                                                                <!---->
                                                                <records-form-footer lwc-rjusaruus2="" class="slds-docked-form-footer" lwc-34n15cmj79s-host="" style="left: 0px;"></records-form-footer>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="screen-announcer slds-assistive-text" aria-live="assertive" lwc-rjusaruus2=""></div>
                                                        </record_flexipage-desktop-record-page-decorator>
                                                    </forcegenerated-flexipage>
                                                </forcegenerated-adg-rollup_component___force-generated__flexipage_-record-page>
                                            </one-record-home-flexipage2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

Is this due to the way the page is constructed ? Is there any workaround ?

I can't recreate this in jsFiddle; is any of your html dynamically generated?

I think so yes I did not write it is from a salesforce web application I use for work.

You need to delay the code that calls querySelector() until after the dynamic elements are created. If you're trying to add event listeners, use event delegation.

But when I run querySelector() directly in firefox console after all the elements are visible in the Inspector view, the code should find them right ?

You should really review your question and reduce the amount of code you are supplying to only the code required to recreate the issue.

Unable to reproduce in Firefox unless the HTML from the post is loaded into an iframe - the you have to select the iframe before running console code related to the iframe's content. Please try and update the post with code for a minimal reproducible example

I CAN reproduce in SFDC rendered environments, and query selector does not work with the rendered Flexipage SFDC elements. I don't know why.
